# Print CMTime in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have some experience of swift, but zero knowledge on objective C
I need to print a timestamp in the console,
here it is:

```
  CMTime timeStamp = CMTimeMake(frame.timeStampNs / rtc::kNumNanosecsPerMillisec, 1000);
```

I added something like that:

```
NSLog(@timeStamp);
```

But it's failed, I need to print something like that in swift:

```
print("Timestamp: \(timeStamp)"
```

Could you please tell me how to do it on objective c?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the format specifier `%f` for 64-bit floating-point numbers (double)

```
NSLog("Timestamp: %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(timeStamp));
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Thanks, how I can change it to show in millisecond, not seconds

Comment: @Martinsku multiply the seconds by 1000 (it won't lose accuracy since it's a decimal)

Comment: Thank you so much, something like that on objective-c ->
NSLog("Timestamp: %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(timeStamp) * 1000);

Comment: Yup that should do it!